# Could not resolve dependencies while building in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Hi I am trying to build a maven project.
After building initial projects successfully, its failing. The error shows that it failed to collect dependency from a particular location in the local repository.

When I went to that location the jar files are missing in it. So I guess it is supposed to download from the remote repository.

I am wondering whether it fails to download or I am getting anything wrong? Also a few posts suggest to delete the .m2 folder.  Will that cause any problems or am I suppose to delete the few folders in it?

Thanks

Comment: Once it failed during the download, it will remember this failure until -U

Comment: Please put your maven error output here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force update dependencies with the switch `-U`. At least you can be sure that it is not because of your local error in .m2.

Comment: Thanks @Simon. will the command be like mvn clean install -U ?

Comment: Put the option before the target.

Comment: Unfortunately the error still persists. can i delete the entire .m2 folder. is that okay or will that create any problem.

Comment: It is ok to delete it.

Comment: Hey Simon Zambrovski, Was able to resolve the issue.
Had to comment out few depencencies (which had no impact on the other modules).
Though still not sure whether the error which was about the missing jar was due to maven not able to download or may be the file may have been removed from the remote repository.

Thanks for your help !!